# Fetch Max-Distict values from MySQL

Tags: mysql, max, distinct

I have a table in database. A user(Name) with a serial no(User-no) can play multiple times. Each time user plays, a new id(Id) is generated and it gets stored in the database along with the score(Score). I want to fetch the top three scores from the table where each users' only top scores get displayed.

Table:

---

### Id |  User-no  |   Name  |   Score

### 1  |    1      |   Name1 |   400

### 2  |    2      |   Name2 |   700

### 3  |    3      |   Name3 |   100

### 4  |    2      |   Name2 |   500

### 5  |    4      |   Name4 |   800

### 6  |    3      |   Name3 |   200

### 7  |    1      |   Name1 |   500

### 8  |    4      |   Name4 |   700

Result should be:

---

### Id |  User-no  |   Name  |   Score

### 5  |    4      |   Name4 |   800

### 2  |    2      |   Name2 |   700

### 7  |    1      |   Name1 |   500

How can I get the above result. I am using MySQL.

Comment: use group by with max

Comment: group by on user no column and select max score

Comment: I was thinking that too, but that can return max(score) with fields from a different row

Comment: What you mean by that??

Comment: that select returns row 1 with the max from row 5 (on mysql 5.5.40-0+wheezy1 that I tried it on)

Answer (score 1):

this can be done with a join on a derived table, though you'd need the right index for it to be efficient

```
select id, uid, name, score
  from scores
  join (select uid, max(score) as score from scores group by uid) t
 using (uid, score)
 order by score desc
 limit 3;
+------+------+------+-------+
| id   | uid  | name | score |
+------+------+------+-------+
|    5 |    4 | n4   |   800 |
|    2 |    2 | n2   |   700 |
|    7 |    1 | n1   |   500 |
+------+------+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Edit: the right index would be (uid, score).  Derived tables do not have indexes, so mysql would loop through the max scores results and pull up the matching rows from the main table.

Comment: I tried your query on MySQL. But it gives me an error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near join at line 4`

Comment: Maybe a typo?  my table's innodb; when I tried converting to engine=mariadb, it accepted the command but the table remained innodb.  I would expect mariadb to also support derived tables, it's not back-end dependent.

Comment: Ok, that error #1064 is gone. Now I am getting #1054: `Unknown column 'score' in 'from clause'`. I have that column ! Edit: I googled the error and I think it has to do with 'using' keyword. So I gave two different aliases to the two froms. That still didn't help.